# Is mail valid proof-of-residence for Alabama driver's license?

Tags: united-states, legal-terms, definition, residency, alabama

Does anyone have guidance on **official** interpretations of the following listed option for [“Proof of Principal Residence” in the context of Alabama Driver's License issuance](https://www.alea.gov/dps/driver-license/document-requirements-and-fees#heading-accordion-924-6)?:

> U.S. or State Government check or other document mailed to applicants[sic] physical address

I have heard that e.g. a bank statement will **not** fulfil this option, but it's not clear.

So what *is* the official interpretation of this ambiguous phrasing?

- Does it mean "governmental check, *or* other mailed document"?
- Does it mean "mailed governmental check, *or* other mailed governmental document"?
- Or has this *still* not been officially determined in either direction?

---

Personal anecdotes of particular situations would be *extremely* welcome **as comments** — however, as individual DMV employees can act incorrectly for many reasons, including discretionary malice, discretionary grace, ignorance of policy, incorrect training, computer system errors, etc., I am seeking an **authoritative answer** to put the question to rest for good (at least until the law / policy formally changes).

Comment: I myself *have* had bank statements accepted as proof-of-residency when changing my voter registration address within-state, in Morgan County.

Comment: To be clear, there isn't necessary one rule. Different rules may apply, for example, for college tuition determinations and for driver's license determinations, for state tax law, and for child custody determinations.